# After switching from Spring Boot 1.2.8 to 1.3.2 application magically stops working

Tags: spring-boot

After upgrading from Spring Boot 1.2.8 to 1.3.2 my application suddenly stopped working.

Upon application's startup I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 25 more
```

It looks like there is a problem with `ResourceBundleMessageSource` but I do not have any idea why. In version 1.2.8 everything worked like a charm.

This is my `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!--replace with your namespace and version -->
    <groupId>my</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.9.0.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
        <spring.social.version>1.1.2.RELEASE</spring.social.version>
        <spring.social.twitter.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring.social.twitter.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>my.project.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>project.local</id>
            <name>my-project</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>     
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1203-jdbc42</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml file?

Comment: Unrelated to the concrete error I see some problems in your pom. Spring boot already ships many of your dependencies, they're just used if declared. So Spring Boot will provide you a Hibernate implementation just in case of declaring the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, you don't need to manually add your own dependency. Something similar happens with joda-time (you need to specify just the dependency without the version), java-mail (there's already a starter module for java mail) javax.json (spring boot already provides and works with the jackson processor).

Comment: In light of the above, just take care about the dependencies, you might pollute your classpath in case of using different versions than the ones provided by the framework (which are BTW, tested to work well). Your concrete error says Spring couldn't find any bean to autowire your dependency. I see in your pom you're missing the `spring-boot-starter` dependency, so try to tidy it up and rerun.

Comment: How come it worked like a charm with the previous version?

Comment: To have it working doesn't guarantee for it to be well-formed :-S

Comment: You are writing about `spring-boot-starter` dependency and it is not even added when using the [Spring Initialzr](http://start.spring.io/) web page.

Comment: Yep, I was looking at  a `spring-cloud` project, which requires it. But be careful about the other ones in your pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have one or more `messages_${locale}.properties` files but don't have a `messages.properties` file. From the [1.3.2 release announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2016/01/22/spring-boot-1-3-2-released):

> If you are upgrading from 1.3.1 there is one potentially breaking change; we now only search for `messages.properties` (and not `messages*.properties`) to enable auto-configuration of a message source. If you previously had a message file of the form `messages_en.properties` and you didn’t include a default `messages.properties` file, you will now need to add one.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with Spring Boot version 1.3.2 itself. I have fallen back to version 1.3.1 and it works superb. It is also true that I do not have `messages.properties` file, only `messages_en.properties`. After renaming `messages_en.properties` to `message.properties` it works like a charm again. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to drop back to 1.3.1. Spring Boot 1.3.2 will work fine as long as you have a file named `message.properties`. You should always have such a file as it's a fallback for anyone in a locale for which you don't have a specific translation.

Comment: Maybe I did not express myself clearly. I am using 1.3.2 now. The fallback was just to check whether it was the current version that had made problems. Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear you're on 1.3.2 and everything's working well now.

Comment: In this case, what happens if I have this in application.properties: _spring.messages.basename=messages/base_? I already have a base.properties file in my "base" resource bundle but the messages aren't picked up for some reason. Any idea why?

Answer (score -2):

@Jagger, @XtremeBiker point is valid to use the parent dependencies which will in turn include all required libraries on its own & you end up with clean pom file as well. Reason why your earlier version spring-boot project was working is that you had all required dependencies in place but its quite common that on any successive SPRING release some dependencies were removed while some are included & hence its highly likely it would break any working code after an update.

Now about the above issue, it can be seen that `ResourceBundleMessageSource` is missing on your project classpath so pls include the latest version of spring-context & try :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding this dependency unfortunately did not solve the problem. I will try with a clean pom.xml generated by [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/) and try do add missing dependencies step by step. Maybe it will help.

Comment: This answer is very misleading. The exception complains  about a missing bean, not a missing class.
Also Spring Boot includes all necessary Spring artifacts, and you should never specify a specific version for a single artifact, which is managed by the Spring Boot Parent POM. Otherwise it is guaranteed, that you will run into problems when upgrading Spring Boot.

Comment: @dunni, ppl here are to help others and one should never keep his opinion on top of others.